# getting error as org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: Property 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD' in date field of xslt

Tags: xslt, xsd

I am getting error as
org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: Property 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD' while validating xsd with xml input at date field.
In xsd it is like  <xsd:element name="CreateTime" type="xsd:dateTime">

and in xslt it is <xsl:value-of select="current-dateTime()"/>

Please help in solving above issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The application that invokes the XML parser is asking it not to access any external DTD by setting the property `http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD`. This is a "standard" property defined in the JAXP specification, but it was only added in later versions, so older XML parsers do not support it, and throw this error if it is requested.

This is nothing to do with the content of your XML, XSD, or XSLT. It's all to do with the configuration of the software components in your application (which you've told us nothing about: you didn't even mention it was Java.)